# Ajax only working first time

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

http://jsfiddle.net/tigreton/JGNmK/

You can see in the fiddle the code.

It loads the #mod-pregunta and #mod-respuesta divs well. And the link too. But if I click it one more time, it doesn't load anything. What do you think is happening? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$(".vote1").html("<a href=\"\" title=\""+ id_pregunta + "-"+ id_respuesta + "-1\" class=\"vote1\" id=\""+ id_pregunta + "-"+ id_respuesta + "-1\" name=\"mod_up\">Aceptar</a>");
```

To

```
$(".vote1").replaceWith("<a href=\"\" title=\""+ id_pregunta + "-"+ id_respuesta + "-1\" class=\"vote1\" id=\""+ id_pregunta + "-"+ id_respuesta + "-1\" name=\"mod_up\">Aceptar</a>");
```

And use jQuery `live` to attach `click` event handler to the above anchor element.

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery's live() function to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

It can't load anything, because jsfiddle do not host mod_up_vote.php

However, on your server, try to use .live() or .delegate()

Comment: Yes, i know that it doesn't work there. Just trying to show my code. I'll try delegate.